# How can you set a bool variable to true and false at the same time?

Tags: lua

I've had this stuck in my head for a while and haven't been able to know how to do it, or if it's even possible!

I'm trying to get the output: "true"

```
local a=true

if a==true then
    if a==false then
        print("true")
    else
        print("false")
    end
elseif a==false then
    if a==true then
        print("true")
    else
        print("false")
    end
end
```

Comment: A variable cannot simultaneously hold two values, in this case both a truthy and falsy value. Every variable holds a single value, and each value is exclusively truthy or falsy. The boolean expression `(a == true and a == false)` will never evaluate to `true` for any value.

Answer (score 0):

a bool can be either true or false, to get the output "true" in this example, you would need to change the value of a.

Comment: Getting the output of `"true"` is impossible for every value of `a` with the given logic structure. There is no value for `a` that would cause the script to print `"true"`.